# Wildfly & Postgre: Missing default datasource issue

Tags: xml, postgresql, netbeans, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to run my service on terminal. It's almost ok, just the missing default datasource error that still there even after a lot of researches on google. Let me explain

I'm using wildfly 10.1.0

this is my datasource in standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS" pool-name="PostgreSQLDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lucasmucida</connection-url>
        <driver>postgresql</driver>
        <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>xxx</user-name>
            <password>xxx</password>
        </security>
        <statement>
            <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
            <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSourc</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

this is the part os standalone.xml that contains the defaul-binding

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
                <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
                <concurrent>
                    <context-services>
                        <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                    </context-services>
                    <managed-thread-factories>
                        <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                    </managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-executor-services>
                        <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                    </managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                        <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                    </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                </concurrent>
                <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/lucasmucida" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
            </subsystem>
```

this is my module.xml that is inside the /modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql/main folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.postgresql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-42.1.4.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
     <module name="javax.api"/>
     <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

If I run sh standalone.sh it creates even a table in the lucasmucida database, but the error:

```
17:38:49,984 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "jpa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.lucasmucida"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"jpa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"jpa2-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.lucasmucida]"]
}
17:38:49,988 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "testeJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.lucasmucida"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.\"testeJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".\"testeJava-1.0-SNAPSHOT\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.lucasmucida]"]
}
```

don't let me run it on netbeans. If I run the project, it creates the table, but doesn't deploy and start the project.

If i go to localhost:9090 and test the connections, both datasources are connecting fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you check your `default-binding` setting inside of the `urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0` subsystem in your standalone.xml?  Depending on how you configured this you may have removed the `datasource` parameter for the default bindings.

Comment: I have edited mny post with the default-bindings configurations. I don't know if there is something wrong with it

Comment: Try to change your default-binding back to the default datasource of `java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS`.  You don't need to modify that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just place the driver.jar at your **module.xml** location